# select related to max field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: laptop, pc, printer with model and price fields.

I need to get max price among all products in these all tables.

I did union to get max price & model field for each table:

```
SELECT model,price 
FROM  (SELECT model, price 
       FROM pc 
       WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc)
       UNION
       SELECT model, price 
       FROM laptop 
       WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop)
       UNION
       SELECT model, price 
       FROM printer WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer)
      ) AS X
```

As a result of this, I received

model   |   price

---

```
 1233  | 980.0000
 1276  | 400.0000
 1288  | 400.0000
 1750  | 1200.0000
```

And now I'm stuck getting only model (in this case it will be '1750') with max price.

Comment: Huh? Can you post some details about your tables, data and what you want? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: One way to do it would be sorting the MAX price at the end instead of at each level of the union. e.g. `SELECT model, price FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Price DESC) FROM (SELECT model, price FROM pc UNION ALL SELECT model, price FROM laptop UNION ALL SELECT model, price FROM printer) AS T) AS T WHERE RN = 1;`

Comment: http://prnt.sc/eq934p - here is db structure for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

How about using `order by` and `top`?

```
SELECT TOP 1 model, price
FROM  (SELECT model, price 
       FROM pc 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT model, price 
       FROM laptop 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT model, price 
       FROM printer
      ) t
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Note:  If you have indexes, this is probably not the most efficient way to get the information you want.  You would need to provide more information about the design of the tables and their data if performance is an issue.

Comment: You beat me by seconds... Just to mention: It might be necessary to use `WITH TIES`, if you expect more than one product with an identical highest price... Otherwise OP's result is rather random...

Answer (score 1):

using `union all` and `top 1`

```
select top 1 model, price 
from (
    select top 1 model, price 
    from pc 
    order by price desc

    union all

    select top 1 model, price 
    from laptop 
    order by price desc

    union all

    select top 1 model, price 
    from printer
    order by price desc
  ) as u
order by price desc
```

<s>I do not know if this will create a different execution plan than Gordon's answer... I'm off to go find out.</s>

This answer produces the [same query execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r17qhoF3l) as Gordon's answer in SQL Server 2012, and as Gordon's is more concise I would go with that one.

Comment: As in Gordon's answer: What, if there is more than one product with the same hightest price? You might add `WITH TIES` to deal with this...

Comment: @Shnugo I'm familiar with `with ties`, but I did not get the impression that was what OP was looking for.

Comment: well, I got the impression, that OP was not aware of this possibility :-D. But in the example there are two products with the same highest price, they might be the total highest. In this case the returned product is rather random...